# how to write a word to a database that is between 2 Apostrophes?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table in my database of type nvarchar(50);
I want to write to that specific column that string 'Tal' - Tal between 2 apostrophes.
When I'm trying to do so what is recorded in my DB is "Tal" - Tal between 2 quotation marks.
My database is an SQL database and so are my scripts.
How this can be solved?

Comment: And what if I want to save a string like this: aaaaa '%s' bbbbb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do what you want is this.

```
 insert into mytable ( mycolumn ) values ('''Tal''');
```

The first and last `'` are the start and end markers for the string.  Each `''` within these characters means `'`.  Refer to page 89 of the SQL 92 specification at http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Lest say I have this string: 'a' 'b' 'c'. How can I convert it to '''a''' '''b''' '''c'''?

Comment: Actually, if you're going to insert `'a' 'b' 'c'` into your database, the part of your SQL statement that comes after `values` needs to be `('''a'' ''b'' ''c''')` - and how you convert your string into that depends on which language you're programming in.

Answer (score 0):

I think escaping is the key to your question. For SQL apostrophes are special characters, thus they have to be escaped by '' (two apostrophes). Have you checked that your scripts do not add the second apostrophe for you? Probably you have to add *Tal* without the apostrophes.

Escape % seems to be DB dependant. Oracles uses \%, others accespt [%] and some seem to have a keyword ESCAPE. You have read the documentation of your database, look for "escape characters".

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting like this using the backslash `\'Tal\'`.

Comment: This is absolutely not standard SQL.  Can you please indicate which databases this works in?  I don't think I know of any, and I have used Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase, DB2, MySQL, Ingres and Microsoft Access.